# v-for through items based on v-model value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a small form where users can submit new photos and see the photos previously submitted under the form. At the beginning of the form, the user selects the album the photo goes in and then uploads. The issue I'm having is how to get the photos based on what album they choose. Sample:

```
<select v-model="newPhoto.album">
  <option value="">Select Album</option>
  <option v-for="album in albums" :value="album['.key']">{{album.name}}</option>
</select>

<ul>
  <li v-for="img in album">{{img.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

I know this would work if the UL was nested in the option but due to my page structure that is not an option. How do I pass the correct album to repeat through the images in the album? The data structure is like so:

```
-Album Firebase ID
  images
    -Photo Firebase ID
      src:
      name:
```

Comment: Do you have to use the `.key` value of the album as the value? Why not just use `album`?

Comment: I needed the key specifically for how I push data to Firebase.

Comment: You would still have that because you have the album.

Comment: Good point. Thanks, I am still learning JS. But does that do anything for the issue of getting that album to the `ul`?

Comment: Sure, because then you would just do `img in newPhoto.album.imgs` assuming you have a list of images in your album somewhere.

Comment: I got:
`"TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of undefined"` when trying `img in newPhoto.album.images`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were stuck using the selected key instead of the album, here is what I might do.

```
computed:{
  selectedAlbum(){
    return this.albums.find(a => a['.key'] === this.newPhoto.album)
  }
}
```

And in your template

```
<ul v-if="newPhoto.album">
  <li v-for="img in selectedAlbum.imgs">{{img.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

And here is an [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/xdyOez).

Here is what it might look like if you use the album as the value of your select. No need for a computed.

```
<select v-model="newPhoto.album">
  <option value="">Select Album</option>
  <option v-for="album in albums" :value="album">{{album.name}}</option>
</select>

<ul>
  <li v-for="img in newPhoto.album.imgs">{{img.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

An [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/aWRZrG) of that.